# Не получается определить собственный id vk

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

День добрый, помогите ради всяго святого. Не получается определить нормально 'me'
Выдает ошибку:

`my_id = requests.get(start, headers = headers).json()['me']['id'] KeyError: 'me'`

Код

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import time
import requests
import random
import config
import os

authorization = config.authorization
job_name = 'А'

start = 'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/start'
buyFetter = 'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/buyFetter'
jobSlave = 'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/jobSlave'
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
 'authorization': authorization,
 'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 YaBrowser/21.2.4.172 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36' 
 }
my_id = requests.get(start, headers = headers).json()['me']['id']
my_top_friend_list = 'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/topFriends'
my_slave_list = f'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/slaveList?id={my_id}'
buySlave = 'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/buySlave'
sellSlave = 'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/saleSlave'

def passive_mode():

    r = requests.get(start, headers = headers).json()

    for slave in r['slaves']:

        if (slave['fetter_to'] == 0 and slave['fetter_price'] < 120000) and (slave['job']['name'] == ''):

            requests.post(buyFetter, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
            print('{}. Купил оковы для @id{}'.format(time.asctime()[11:19], slave['id']))
            time.sleep(1.5)
            requests.post(jobSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id'],
                                                                        'name' : random.choice(job_name)}))
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('{}. Назначил работу для @id{}'.format(time.asctime()[11:19], slave['id']))
        elif slave['fetter_to'] == 0 and slave['fetter_price'] < 120000:
            requests.post(buyFetter, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
            print('{}. Купил оковы для @id{}'.format(time.asctime()[11:19], slave['id']))
            time.sleep(2)

    time.sleep(random.randint(10,15))

def attack_mode(ID, auto):

    enemy = f'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/slaveList?id={ID}'

    r = requests.get(enemy, headers = headers).json()

    n = 0

    for slave in r['slaves']:
        
        if (slave['fetter_to'] == 0 and slave['price'] < 120000):
            requests.post(buySlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
            if (slave['profit_per_min'] < 700 and auto):
                ID = slave['id']
                slave_info = f'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/user?id={ID}'
                slave_profit = slave['profit_per_min']
                while slave_profit < 1000:
                    requests.post(sellSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    requests.post(buySlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    requests.post(jobSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id'],
                                                                                'name' : job_name}))
                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    slave_profit = requests.get(slave_info, headers = headers).json()['profit_per_min']
                    time.sleep(1.5)
            requests.post(buyFetter, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
            time.sleep(1.5)
            requests.post(jobSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id'],
                                                                        'name' : job_name}))
            n += 1

            print(f'{time.asctime()[11:19]}. Украл {n}-го раба.')
    print(f'{time.asctime()[11:19]}. Украл {n} рабов.')

def upgrade_mode(n):

    r = requests.get(my_slave_list, headers = headers).json()

    i = 0

    for slave in r['slaves']:
        if slave['profit_per_min'] < 1000 and i<n:
            ID = slave['id']
            slave_info = f'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/user?id={ID}'
            slave_profit = slave['profit_per_min']
            while slave_profit < 1000:
                requests.post(sellSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
                time.sleep(0.4)
                requests.post(buySlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
                time.sleep(0.4)
                requests.post(jobSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id'],
                                                                            'name' : job_name}))
                time.sleep(0.4)
                slave_profit = requests.get(slave_info, headers = headers).json()['profit_per_min']
                time.sleep(0.4)
            requests.post(buyFetter, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : slave['id']}))
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('{}. Прокачал раба @id{}'.format(time.asctime()[11:19], slave['id']))
            i += 1

def farm_mode(time_):
    if time_ == 0:
        time_ = 999999999
    t = time.time()
    n = 0
    while t + time_ > time.time():
        n += 1
        ID = random.randint(1000000, 99999999)
        rand_slave_info = f'https://pixel.w84.vkforms.ru/HappySanta/slaves/1.0.0/user?id={ID}'
        try:
            rand_slave = requests.get(rand_slave_info, headers = headers).json()
            if (rand_slave['fetter_to'] == 0 and rand_slave['price'] < 88000):
                requests.post(buySlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : rand_slave['id']}))
                time.sleep(0.5)
                requests.post(buyFetter, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : rand_slave['id']}))
                time.sleep(0.5)
                requests.post(jobSlave, headers = headers, data = json.dumps({'slave_id' : rand_slave['id'],
                                                                            'name' : job_name}))
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('{}. Купил @id{} за {} + оковы за {}'.format(time.asctime()[11:19], rand_slave['id'], rand_slave['price'], rand_slave['fetter_price']))
                if n % 10 == 0:
                    print('\n{}. У вас {} рабов.\n'.format(time.asctime()[11:19], requests.get(start, headers = headers).json()['me']['slaves_count']))
        except:
            pass

def menu(ex):
    os.system('cls')
    print('ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4\n')
    r = requests.get(start, headers = headers).json()
    print('Ваш баланс : {}\nКоличество ваших рабов : {}\nВаш профит в минуту : {}\nПозиция в топе : {}'.format(r['me']['balance'],  r['me']['slaves_count'], r['me']['slaves_profit_per_min'], r['me']['rating_position']))
    print('''
               Выберите режим:
1) Passive Mode (защита рабов обновляющимися оковами)
2) Attack Mode (выкуп выгодных рабов у выбранного пользователя + возможноть автопрокачки)
3) Upgrade Mode (прокачка рабов до 1000 р/мин)
4) Farm Mode (фарм рабов)
''')
    if ex:
        print('Произошла ошибка. Произведен автоматический выход в меню.\n')
    choice = input('>>> ')
    if choice == '1':
        os.system('cls')

        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

На сколько времени? (в минутах, 0 - без ограничений)
''')
        time_ = int(input('>>> ')) * 60
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

Passive Mode

Logs:
''')
        if time_ == 0:
            while True:
                passive_mode()
        else:
            time_ += time.time()
            while time_ > time.time():
                passive_mode()
            menu(0)
    elif choice == '2':
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

Включить автопрокачку? (1 - да / 0 - нет)
            ''')
        choice = input('>>> ')
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

Введите ID жертвы.
            ''')
        ID = input('>>> ')

        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

Attack Mode.

Logs :
''')
        try:
            attack_mode(int(ID), int(choice))
            menu(0)
        except:
            menu(1)

    elif choice == '3':
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

Сколько рабов прокачать?
''')
        slaves_for_up = int(input('>>> '))
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR Slave Bot v1.4

Upgrade Mode

Logs:
''')
        upgrade_mode(slaves_for_up)
        menu(0)
    elif choice == '4':
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR slave bot v1.4

На сколько времени? (в минутах, 0 - без ограничений)
''')
        time_ = int(input('>>> ')) * 60
        os.system('cls')
        print('''ShiZZZeRRR Slave Bot v1.4

Farm Mode

Logs:
''')
        farm_mode(time_)
        menu(0)
    else:
        menu(1)

menu(0)
```

Comment: очевидно, что ваш словарь не имеет такого ключа, посмотрите, что вы получаете в json'e

Comment: Как это можно сделать? Только начинаю изучать питон и пока что многое непонятно

Comment: Попытался определить me внутри headers и получил в консоли ошибок столько, что и смотреть страшно

Comment: Еще утром код работал, значит headers перестал получать me из токена приложения...

Comment: `print(requests.get(start, headers = headers).json())` посмотрите, что выводит